# Slow performance with Testcafe and ids and custom radio buttons

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test where testcafe says "Waiting for element to appear" and I dont understand why.
I use a ID selector

My test is fairly simple and I made a slow version using a ID and a fast one using a non ID

Is this a bug in testcafe?

Using Testcafe v1.11.0 on Chrome 88.0.4324.182 / Windows 10

Test output says:

```
 Book
 √ slow  (17s)
 √ fast  (3.69s)
```

Why is selecting using ID so much slower? Shouldn't it be faster?

This is my test:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture('Book').page('https://book.dinnerbooking.com/dk/en-US/book/table/pax/458/2');

test('slow', async t => {
    'use strict';
    await t
        .maximizeWindow()
        .click('button.ui-spinner-up')
        .click('button.black-button')
        .click('#RestaurantAreaConfigAreaId6');
});

test('fast', async t => {
    'use strict';
    await t
        .maximizeWindow()
        .click('button.ui-spinner-up')
        .click('button.black-button')
        .click(new Selector('.restaurant-area-label').nth(1));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

These two different selectors select two different elements. `'#RestaurantAreaConfigAreaId6'` selects the `<input type="radio" id="RestaurantAreaConfigAreaId6" ... />` element and `Selector('.restaurant-area-label').nth(1)` selects the `<label for="RestaurantAreaConfigAreaId6" class="restaurant-area-label font-large">Café</label>` element.

The `input` element, in turn, is overlapped by another transparent element. In such cases, TestCafe waits until the target element becomes uncovered within the [timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html#selector-timeout). If the target element stays still, TestCafe clicks on the element above.